# javascript email validation , can't get indexOf work

Tags: javascript, html

here is my html code:

```
 <input id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email"  required>
 <button type="submit" id="submitButton">SUBMIT</button>
```

js code:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');


submitButton.onclick = function(){
  if(email.value == "")
        alert("Please enter correct email");
        return false;
if(email.indexOf("@") < 1 || email.lastIndexOf(".") - email.indexOf("@") <2)
        alert("Please enter correct email");
        return false;
else
        return(true);
```

The error message always the same : TypeError: email.indexOf is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.submitButton.onclick

Comment: You're using `indexOf` on an element, not text. Try `email.value.indexOf`

Comment: @evolutionxbox, jesus.... can't believe I wrote this code , cha cha. Thanks , mate if you want I can make your answer as correct if you post an answer

Comment: Nah, thanks anyway. Use @brk's answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You need the value of the input element.
`email = document.getElementById('email')` will return the input element but not it's value

Make this change

`var email = document.getElementById('email').value`;

Comment: yup , thanks mate ;)I'll mark your answer as correct , okay ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for email. Its easier to use regex to do so. See example below on how to do it.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

It uses basic regex that a lot of resources reference for checking type of email.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

function validate() {
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#email").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " is valid :)");
    $("#result").css("color", "green");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " is not valid :(");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("#validate").bind("click", validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' id='validate'>Validate!</button>
</form>

<h2 id='result'></h2>
```